# Disabling monitor reconfiguration when closing lid

Tags: xorg, multiple-monitors, external-monitor

I often need to move my laptop from one working place to another. When I do this, there are two events Ubuntu responds to by changing the monitor set up:

- Removing/attaching the VGA cable
- Closing/opening the lid of the laptop

While removing the VGA cable gives me what I need (single screen, highest native resolution on the external screen if connected; otherwise highest resolution on the laptop), the laptop close/open lid response is not as good.

Every time I close or open the lid, Ubuntu reconfigures the monitor set up. When I close the lid now... the screen goes black for a few seconds and it switches to clone, with my laptop screen disabled. Reopening results in... briefly a black screen, then the external monitor being used as desktop extension.

**Update: Things changed a bit recently, the behaviour is more predictable now. Closing the lid switches to single display, opening to dual screen (not clone). My question is still accurate: see below.**

Ubuntu thinks too much. My first and foremost question: **Is there any way to let Ubuntu ignore lid close events?**

Ideally (or when there's no way to solve above question) I'd want to change *how* it deals with the screen reconfiguration. Why does Ubuntu toggle the screen configuration between external, clone and single display? Can't I just configure it to always use the external monitor, when present, in single screen mode?

Note that similar questions have been asked before (most notably [this one](https://askubuntu.com/questions/58961/do-nothing-when-closing-laptop-lid-doesnt-work)), but these have been closed perhaps wrongly.

Any ideas are very welcome, I don't mind playing around a bit to see if something works.

Comment: For those still interested, questions appear from other people with similar issues:
http://askubuntu.com/questions/161649/how-do-i-disable-all-lid-close-processes

Comment: I noticed this question is still getting a couple of views per week. I've switched to Arch Linux a while ago and noticed that lid close events are completely ignored by default, not even a screen flicker is seen. It might be that a newer Linux kernel fixes the issues described in this question (both desktop environments I use completely ignore the lid if I tell them to). If so, it is very likely that newer releases of Ubuntu include/will include this fix.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> Is there any way to let Ubuntu ignore lid close events?

Lid events are triggered by the `lidbtn` file in `/etc/acpi/events/`, which contains two active lines:

```
event=button[ /]lid
action=/etc/acpi/lid.sh -- comment this out with a # at the beginning
```

You can ignore lid open/close events by commenting out the second line with a `#` and then rebooting.

> I'd want to change how it deals with the screen reconfiguration.

You can look at and try to modify the file `/etc/acpi/lid.sh` and the functions/commands it references.

**BUT (BIG CAVEAT):** If your laptop BIOS uses the lid close/open to switch the internal/external video out ports on/off, then this is beyond the OS ACPI event handler's powers.

Comment: Looks interesting but commenting out the 2nd line does not solve my problem. Diving into the `lid.sh` file suggests it handles switching off the screen (commands like `xscreensaver-command -unthrottle`, `xscreensaver-command -deactivate`, `/usr/share/acpi-support/screenblank` and `xset dpms force on`). Nothing is mentioned about switching or detecting screens (I was expecting `xrandr` or something for this).
Any more tips?

Comment: Temporarily move `lidbtn` from `/etc/acpi/events` to someplace else, say `~/` . Does that help?

Comment: Doesn't change anything, as far as I can tell this has the exact same effect as leaving the file there. Have tried rebooting to make sure the change is applied, of course.

Comment: @Tomas: see edit at bottom of the answer.

Comment: good point. I'll see if I can find anything in my BIOS and will update this edit if I run into anything.
Thanks a lot for all the time you put into this :)

Comment: you might very well be right about the caveat. Unfortunately I can't find any options in the bios to change this.

Comment: As far as I can tell there is no way to disable the resolution glitch and I do not know if the same thing happens on other laptops as well; could be a problem of my laptop model.
I will stick with your answer, @izx. Thanks for your help, the bounty is coming your way :)

Comment: Thanks @Tomas! I am coming to the same conclusion--that this is a hardware specific issue--based on [this question](http://askubuntu.com/questions/148725/laptop-screen-blank-after-login-when-external-monitor-is-not-connected) from another poor chap with an external monitor issue.

Comment: On my Ubuntu 14.04 I neither have a `lid.sh` nor a `lidbtn` on my system (searched with `locate`) Can I create one of these to add some functionality (I want to [disable my touchscreen on closing laptop lid](https://askubuntu.com/q/525878))?

Answer (score 0):

This behavior is a Gnome feature, and it is controlled by a dconf setting. You can change it via `dconf-editor` or directly using command line:

```
gsettings set org.gnome.settings-daemon.plugins.xrandr default-monitors-setup <value>
```

The description says following:

> Summary: Whether to turn off specific monitors after boot
>
> 'clone' will display the same thing on all monitors, 'dock' will switch off the internal monitor, 'do-nothing' will use the default Xorg behaviour (extend the desktop in recent versions). The default, 'follow-lid', will choose between 'do-nothing' and 'dock' depending on whether the lid is (respectively) open or closed.

So, if you'd like to use only the external monitor when it is connected, use `dock` as `<value>`.

If you want both monitors to always work, no matter if lid is closed or not, use `do-nothing`. (I often closed the lid temporarily just so that it did not shine into my dark room, I didn't want all windows to migrate to external monitor.)

And finally, if you want to use laptop screen but only when it is open, use `follow-lid`. (Use case: amount of free space on your desk varies, and sometimes you have to put the laptop behind your monitor instead of beside it.)

Comment: Almost 4 years later, I had this very problem again, and spent an hour googling before vaguely remembering that I might have answered that question myself a while back... And viola, here it is! Still wirking. Still with zero votes. And I still couldn't google it up, found it by looking through questions I answered here.

Answer (score 0):

> Can't I just configure it to always use the external monitor, when present, in single screen mode?

I can answer this part. I run ubuntu 17.10 on wayland. In the `gnome-control-center -> device -> display`, you can choose `single display` with only the `$external_monitor` enabled, then click on "apply". That generates a `$HOME/.confg/monitors.xml` file. The file fixes the display arragemment when the same `$external_monitor` is connected, and toggles on the internal monitor once it's disconnected. What's better, you can put the same `monitors.xml` in `/var/lib/gdm3/.config/`, in that case the same thing holds for GDM too.