# How do I disable all lid close processes?

Tags: power-management

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How can I tell Ubuntu to do nothing when I close my laptop lid?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/15520/how-can-i-tell-ubuntu-to-do-nothing-when-i-close-my-laptop-lid)

I want to be able to close my laptop without Ubuntu registering it. I've been looking everywhere and I've found plenty of people with the same problem but no real solutions. Obviously I have set the lid close setting to 'do nothing' for both AC and battery, but when I close the lid it still blanks the screen, disconnects from external monitors, and brings up the lock screen when I reopen it. Some people have suggested disabling the lock screen, but this doesn't stop the screen blanking and external displays disconnecting, and I don't want to disable the lock anyway, as I still want it when I tell Ubuntu to lock or sleep or whatever else.

Others have suggested it's something to do with ACPI support, but I have tried changing some ACPI scripts, and even removed them completely (e.g. `/etc/acpi/lid.sh` and `/etc/acpi/events/lidbtn`) and it makes no difference. There must be a bit of code somewhere that can just be removed or commented out or altered to prevent any lid close actions - does anyone know where?

I know this has been asked before, but I'm getting really frustrated with this problem. I'm disappointed to say that I'm actually using Windows 7 more often just because it's quite happy to completely ignore the closed lid. So I just wanted to check, are we any closer to a real solution for this problem?

Comment: I asked a similar question a few weeks ago:
http://askubuntu.com/questions/145342/disabling-monitor-reconfiguration-when-closing-lid
We ended up with this being a BIOS issue, though if you manage to reproduce it with different hardware, something fishy could be going on.

Comment: Thanks for closing my question. I had seen yours, but felt that my question was less specific and so perhaps relevant to more people - you don't have to be using a second display for this lid close thing to be a problem.

Comment: Also, as stated above, I don't have any trouble with Windows 7 ignoring the lid close, so it must be Ubuntu rather than BIOS, right? [I wanted to add this comment to your question, but I'm not able to do so - if you could add something along these lines I would appreciate it.]

Comment: I added my comment and did not mark it as a duplicate because @Mat managed to reproduce the problem with (very likely) different hardware. IMHO this question should remain open because (i) the problem is not being reported for the first time/seems to be not hardware specific and (ii) this question is less specific than mine.

Comment: @Bruno-Pereira, please take another look at this. I think it is not rightfully marked as duplicate, and should definitely not be marked as duplicate of http://askubuntu.com/questions/15520/how-can-i-tell-ubuntu-to-do-nothing-when-i-close-my-laptop-lid. The poster is asking for a way to make Ubuntu ignore lid close events, which is different from selecting "do nothing" in Power management. "do nothing" still reconfigures the monitors, causing  e.g. changes in resolution and mirror mode toggling.

Comment: I seriously need an answer to this. I essentially remove all acpi events relate to lid and still no effect. Is there any update? Please re-open the question?

Comment: @Anh  You should probably open a new question with the details for your case.