# Closing lid turns off external monitor on 16.04

Tags: multiple-monitors, display, power-management, laptop, gnome-screensaver

NOTE: Don't rush to mark as duplicate - most of the similar questions consider very old Ubuntu versions and their answers are not applicable.

I have Lenovo T460s with the latest Ubuntu 16.04. I like my lid closed when it's docked / connected to external monitors. However the moment I close the lid, the external monitors are turned off as well.

What I did so far:

- Set "Do nothing" in "When the lid is closed" line of Power settings
- Verified that `#HandleLidSwitchDocked=ignore` exists in `/etc/systemd/logind.conf` (tried uncommenting and restarting - did not change anything)
- Set my monitor LCD screen to OFF (when other monitors are connected)
- In "Brightness&Lock", "Lock" is off, and "Turn screen off when inactive for" is set to 30 minutes

Comment: Did you upgrade from a previous version?

Comment: Nope, fresh install, but copied over my old home directory (I used KDE previously)

Comment: Did you remove the `#` in the line `#HandleLidSwitchDocked=ignore`? Line start with `#` is a comment, no effect...

Comment: `HandleLidSwitchDocked=ignore` is a default one. To be sure,  I've additionally tried and uncommenting and rebooting, but it made no effect.

Answer (score 1):

The external monitor(s) turn off in Kernel `4.4.0-135`. However in Kernel `4.13.0-36` the external monitor(s) simply reset and set Brightness to `1.00` and Gamma to `1.0:1.0:1.0`.

Upgrading kernel would be the simplest way of solving the issue.

As the other answer mentioned simply moving the mouse will wake up the external monitors when using Kernel `4.4.0-135`.

Comment: Can confirm same problem with kernel 4.4.0-185 today.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know how to **prevent** them turning off, but doing something that would otherwise wake the system up (mouse movement, keypress etc.) will turn the external display back on.

Source: [How do I prevent an external monitor from shutting off when closing my laptop lid?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/152156/how-do-i-prevent-an-external-monitor-from-shutting-off-when-closing-my-laptop-li)